# WP8 cannot display images in native resolution

Tags: screen-size

Every image on WP8 is stretched to twice its height regardless of the positioning method.

Cannot display high quality images as they all are resized outsize the visible display port automatically.

Is there a way to disable the resizing?

Thanks

Image in the code below is resized if you run the app on a 720p device or emulator. How to display the original image size exactly?

```
<Canvas >
       <Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid_800x480.png"   Stretch="None" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height & width properties of the Image element.

Comment: If I set ... Height="800" Width="480" ...  image is resized to full screen on 720p device.

Comment: You can put it in a ScrollViewer to make sure it isn't resized if that's what you meant with the comment. (Sorry, I misread the question).